# What is the relative projection of the decomposition $V_{1}\oplus W$ to the second term?

Tags: linear-algebra

We have a matrix

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 & -1 \\ 2 & 2 & -1 \\ 2 & 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

and we want to find a basis of eigenvectors $\beta$ in order that $[L_{A}]_{\beta}$ be a triangular matrix. So $p_{A}(x)=(x-1)(x-2)^2$ is its characteristic polynomial and the vector $X_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector asociated to $\lambda=1$ so we can take the basis $\beta=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$ such that $V=V_{1}\oplus W$ where $V_{1}=\left\langle\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\2\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle$ and $W=\left\langle\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\}\right\rangle$
and the coordinates in the basis $\beta$ can be expressed by

$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z \end{pmatrix}=x\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}+(z-2x)\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}$

and then the text says that this allows us to describe the relative projection to the second term of the decomposition $V=V_{1}\oplus W$ as the matrix

$P=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0\\ 0&1&0 \\ -2&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$

but I don't understand how to obtain this matrix $P$. How do we find the first column $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\-2\end{pmatrix}$?

Edit: it's a process in order to get the basis. You take the matrix B=PA and find an eigenvector for this matrix $X_{2}$ and do the same. So at the end you get the basis $\beta=\{X_{1},X_{2},X_{3}\}$ which makes the matrix $[A]_{\beta}$ triangular The text are class notes https://acatlan.gitlab.io/lineal2/triangulacion.html#trio

Comment: which text? this seems like a weird way of phrasing things because it's not clear what they're trying to project. Also your $\beta$ doesn't consist of eigenvectors (in fact there is no basis of eigenvectors since the matrix is non-diagonalizable (because the Jordan canonical form is non-trivial)).

Comment: @peek-a-boo it's a process in order to get the basis. You take the matrix B=PA and find an eigenvector for this matrix $X_{2}$ and do the same. So at the end you get the basis $\beta=\{X_{1},X_{2},X_{3}\}$ which makes the matrix $[A]_{\beta}$ triangular The text are class notes https://acatlan.gitlab.io/lineal2/triangulacion.html#trio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lol, ok I realised why I confused myself in the comments (I did the calculation too quickly in my head which gave me a different result from what's posted).

Anyway, what's going on is that the direct sum decomposition $V=\Bbb{F}^3=V_1\oplus W$ gives us a projection $P_W:V\to V$ with image $W$; said another way, for each $v\in V$, there exist unique $v_1\in V_1,w\in W$ such that $v=v_1+w$. Then, we define $P_W(v):= w$. Now, the matrix they're talking about is the matrix representation of the operator $P_W$ relative to the standard basis $\sigma=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ on the domain and target of $V=\Bbb{F}^3$.

You've already written down how vectors can be decomposed relative to the basis $\beta$:
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}&=
x
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
2
\end{pmatrix}
+ y
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
+ (z-2x)
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
0\\
2x
\end{pmatrix}}_{\in V_1}
+
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
y\\
z-2x
\end{pmatrix}}_{\in W}
\end{align}
Therefore, the mapping $P_W$ is given as follows: $P_W:V\to V$,
\begin{align}
P_W\left(\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}\right)&:=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
y\\
z-2x
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Now, you can surely calculate the matrix representation of this linear transformation relative to the standard ordered basis $\sigma$:
\begin{align}
[P_W]_{\sigma}&=
\begin{pmatrix}
P_W(e_1)&P_W(e_2)&P_W(e_3)
\end{pmatrix}\\\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0& 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
-2& 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

Comment: btw another (slightly more roundabout) way of describing the mapping $P_W$ is as follows. The internal direct sum $V=V_1\oplus W$ means that the mapping $\phi:V_1\times W\to V$, $\phi(v_1,w):=v_1+w$ is an isomorphism (injectivity is because $V_1\cap W=\{0\}$, surjectivity is because $V_1+W=V$). We can now define a projection $\pi_W:V_1\times W\to V_1\times W$ as $\pi_W(v_1,w)=(0,w)$ (usual cartesian product projection). Then, $P_W$ is defined to be the mapping $\phi\circ\pi_W\circ \phi^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Know I understand the process.

Comment: Oh and if for some reason you ever need to calculate $P_{V_1}$, you can follow the same process, or just do $I-P_{W}$.